# how to get JSON objects from servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I am making a simple html servlet program where I need get JSON object from the servlet, and in html I am able to get the data, but how can i refer to each attribute?

Here is the servlet `get` method

```
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    StringBuffer emps = new StringBuffer("{employees:[");
    emps.append("{fullname:\"Abhishek Raj Simon\"},{email:\"a@a.com\"}]");
    emps.append("}");
    out.println(emps);
```

JS to send

```
function getJson()
{
 var url_action="/temp/jsontest";
 var form=document.forms["mainForm"];
 var splitOutput;
 var client; 
 var dataString;

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
     client=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
     client=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 client.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if(client.readyState==4&&client.status==200)
     {
        var res=client.responseText;
        alert(res);     
        alert(client.responseText.employees.fullname); //DOES NOT WORK
        alert(client.responseText.employees.email); //DOES NOT WORK     
     }
 };

 client.open("GET",url_action,true);
 client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 client.send();
```

and a simple form

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="get me some json" onclick="getJson();">
</form>
```

When i click on the button, i get only 1 alert displaying 
`{employees:[{fullname:"Abhishek Raj Simon"},{email:"a@a.com"}]}` How can i fetch `Abhishek Raj Simon` and `a@a.com` using fullname and email respectively?

**Edited after reading post from Artem**

my servlet

```
    Gson gson = new Gson( );
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    Employee emp=new Employee();
    emp.setFullname("Abhishek Raj Simon");
    emp.setEmail("a@a.com");
    employees.add(emp);
    response.setContentType( "application/json");
    out.println( gson.toJson( employees));
```

js part

```
var res=eval('(' + client.responseText + ')');
        alert(res);     
        alert(res.employees.fullname);
        alert(res.employees.email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should slightly change the JSON that you send form the servlet: `{employees:[{fullname:"Abhishek Raj Simon", email:"a@a.com"}]}` would work a bit better in that context.

I'd recommend jQuery as pap has also advised. The code would be:

```
$.getJSON('/temp/jsontest', function(data) {
   var items = [];
   for (employee in data.employees) {
       items.push(employee.fullname + '<' + employee.email + '>');
   }
   alert('Employees: ' + items.join(', '));
});
```

In my opinion it is lot simpler and easier to understand than dealing with raw XHR. The jQuery `$.getJSON` will do `GET` for you, and then evaluate the JSON response so the function is presented with nice JSON representation of your data that is easy to manipulate.

**EDIT**:

After interesting discussion here is some more improvement you could introduce in order to replace the low-level code with proper JQuery-based implementation.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#json-button").click(function() {
      $.getJSON('/temp/jsontest', function(data) {
        var items = [];
          for (employee in data.employees) {
            items.push(employee.fullname + '<' + employee.email + '>');
          }
          alert('Employees: ' + items.join(', '));
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form>
    <input id="json-button" type="button" value="get me some json">
</form>
```

Comment: @Tomasz: In my case the `getJson()` method is fixed for sending sending request. so how can i still get back the request as JSON Object?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `getJson()` is fixed for sending request? It cant be replaced? Why?

Comment: i am not allowed to use any external library

Comment: OK. I must say I'm confused. Why you are not allowed to use tools like jQuery that **significantly** improve your code? you could implement new function `getJsonWithJQuery` and call it from `onclick` event handler of the `<button>`.

Comment: ok how can i implement a new function and call it from onclick in query?

Comment: Here is how you could do this: https://gist.github.com/994958. Please note that your `getJson()` function is no longer needed. The `onclick` event trigger from the `<button>` has been replaced by proper JQuery event handling i.e. `click()` function.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, which enables you to serialize Java object to json, to avoid writing it by yourself. If you do not want to use GSON, there are plenty of others libraries which uses same capabilities.

```
//inside your get method

Gson gson = new Gson( );
List<Employe> employees = new ArrayList<Employe>( );

// populate your list here

response.setContentType( "application/json");
response.getWriter( ).println( gson.toJson( employees));


//end
```

then in javascript you can do as it's already suggested in other answers here. And do pay attention to update response content type.

Comment: I doubt this solves the issues explained in question. The way the author creates the response on the server side is not the most elegant one, but it produces valid JSON. The issue is on the client side, because the response body is not evaluated as JavaScript.

Comment: I tried the other js methods on this page after downloading Gson library, it is not working, i.e., dosn't show any alert

Comment: @Abhishek Have you ever tried to debug your JavaScript code? Try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) in Firefox to understand exactly what is going on in your code.

Comment: Didn't aimed to answer a question, since by the time I've wrote this post correct answer is already presented here, just wanted to help with small advice suggesting more nicer way to format output on client.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res=client.responseText;
var temp = 'resObj=' + res;
eval(temp);
alert(resObj.employees.fullname);
```

JSON is just text, but in javascript syntax. You need to pass it through the "eval" method that will evaluate and execute the text as javascript.

My advice, though, is to use jQuery or some other javascript framework to avoid having to mess with all that boiler-plate javascript.

Comment: it gives me `undefined`, ok how can i do it using jQuery? can u show an example function from my code? Also how will i call that function from a JS function?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are receiving the JSON String but you're not converting it into a JSON Object. There's a [`eval()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) function that evaluates your JSON String and returns a JSON Object.

The following example should work (though untested).

```
if(client.readyState==4&&client.status==200)
     {
        var res=eval('(' + client.responseText; + ')');
        alert(res);     
        alert(res.employees[0].fullname);
        alert(res.employees[0].email);   
     }
```

**WARNING**: I suggest reading the security concerns when using [`eval()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JavaScript_eval.28.29). Alternatively, go to [JSON.org](http://json.org) and download a Javascript JSON parser or use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.

Comment: thanks for the info. also when i use eval as in your edited code, i get `[object]` from my alert

Comment: @Abhishek Simon, I changed my `alert()` in my code to show the change.

Comment: I got 3 alerts, with the following values `[object,Object]` `undefined` `undefined`

Comment: ok, see my edited post again and see if you can get the result doing `eval(client.responseText);`.